# Use DateTime Format Strings in a Custom DateTimePickerFormat

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, datetimepicker

Everywhere in my code, when dealing with dates, I rely on the [DateTime Format String "G"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime). EXCEPT in the DateTimePicker itself, as I must set a CustomFormat, and the CustomFormat doesn't accept "G" as a valid format specifier. I need this so that the dates will all look the same, independent of culture.

Any thoughts on how I might circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
picker.CustomFormat = DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern +  DateTimeFormatInfo.LongTimePattern
```

This is essentially what the "G" format specifier gives you.